# Store Different Types of Values in One Key - Dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to make a "travel" summary that looks like:

> There are **4** starting points to reach **Chicago**. To access this
>   city, you can use: **Highway X,** **Highway Z,**
>   **Highway ZZ.**

The data that I currently have looks something like:

> Highway X, NY, Chicago
>
> Highway Z, LA, Chicago
>
> Highway X, Austin, Chicago
>
> Highway ZZ, Miami, Chicago

My question: What should I use to store these data properly?

I tried to use a dictionary with a list inside of it. However, it didn't work because I couldn't store the list of Highway. I only managed to get something like

> {Chicago: [NY, LA, Austin]}

**UPDATE!!**

I just figured out that there's duplication in my data, and that's not a good news because I want the starting points to be distinct. Right now it looks like this:

> Highway X, NY, Chicago
>
> Highway X, NY, Chicago
>
> Highway Z, LA, Chicago
>
> Highway X, Austin, Chicago
>
> Highway ZZ, Miami, Chicago
>
> Highway X, NY, Chicago

Comment: So you're trying to figure out the best way to store the data so that for each city, you can see which other cities you can go to?

Comment: @jlarks32 I'm trying to find a way how to store all these data and print them exactly like the summary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list of tuples in your dictionary. The first item in each tuple would be the highway, the second the starting point.

```
routes = {'Chicago': [('Highway X', 'NY'), ('Highway Z', 'LA'), ('Highway AX', 'Austin'), ('Highway ZZ', 'Miami')]}
```

Then it's trivial to produce the summary:

```
for city in routes:
    paths = ', '.join(sorted({route[0] for route in routes[city]}))
    print("There are {} starting points to reach {}. To access this city, you can use: {}".format(len(routes[city]), city, paths))
```

The first line uses a set comprehension to remove duplicate highways and then sorts and joins them to make a string. That string as well as the destination city and number of routes is then used to construct the final summary string. The output of the above code would be:

```
There are 4 starting points to reach Chicago. To access this city, you can use: Highway X, Highway Z, Highway ZZ
```

---

An easy way to construct the `routes` dict is to use a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) of lists. Assuming that your data is coming from a CSV file:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

routes = defaultdict(list)

with open('data.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for highway, start, dest in reader:
        routes[dest].append((highway, start))
```

Comment: Thank you, I've tried this, and it worked! I want to ask a follow-up question. Is it possible to sort the destination cities based on the most starting points? Let's say if my data are Chicago = 4 starting points, Seattle = 12 starting points, and SF = 2 starting points. Then, my code will print Seattle first, then Chicago and SF.

Comment: Hi, I just discovered that there's duplication in my data. Is there a way to eliminate this duplication when I append?

Comment: Re duplicates:: yes, use a set of tuples (instead of a list) and change `routes[dest].append()` to `routes[dest].add()`.

Comment: Re: sorting by number of routes, you can sort using a key like this: `for city in sorted(routes, key=lambda key: len(routes[key]), reverse=True):`

Answer (score 1):

The best way of organising your  data depends on what you want to do with them.

Do you want to answer questions like "I'm in Austin, which Highway do I have to take to get to Chicago?"

Then your keys should be the departure cities:

```
lookup = {'Austin': 'Highway X',
          'NY': 'Highway X',
          'LA': 'Highway Z',
          'Miami': 'Highway ZZ'}
```

Because then you can answer the question by simply looking up the asker's starting point:

```
lookup['Austin']
# prints
# Highway X
```

But if you want to answer different questions like "Someone travelling on Highway X which city are they more likely to come from?" then you'd organise your data differently.

If you just want to print them, use a 'lil' (list of lists)

```
table = [["Highway X", "NY", "Chicago"],
         ["Highway Z", "LA", "Chicago"],
         ["Highway X", "Austin", "Chicago"],
         ["Highway ZZ", "Miami", "Chicago"]]
```

Then you can easily format

```
for row in table:
    print("{:12}{:8}{:10}".format(*row))
```

Answer (score 0):

Nest some dictionaries. This allows you to follow a "route."

```
{'Highway X': {'Austin': 'Chicago', 'NY': 'Chicago'},
 'Highway Z': {'LA': 'Chicago'},
 'Highway ZZ': {'Miami': 'Chicago'}}
```

Alternatively:

```
{'Austin': {'Highway X': 'Chicago'},
 'LA': {'Highway Z': 'Chicago'},
 'Miami': {'Highway ZZ': 'Chicago'},
 'NY': {'Highway X': 'Chicago'}}
```

Comment: I will try this out first. Thanks!